# Typescript: How to pass 9999999999999999 through an interface type?

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript.

I am trying to input a value of 9999999999999999, but it changes to 10000000000000000.

My code looks like this:

```
interface Item: {
   Amount: number,
  };
}
```

In a separate .ts file, this is how it looks like

```
SaleReturn {
  Type: 'itemprice',
  ItemAmount: {
    Amount: 0,
    SaleType: '',
  };
}
```

Apologies for the noob question if ever, but how would I be able to fix this?

Comment: Have a look at this article. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Answer (score 2):

The largest value for JavaScript primitive type *number* is 9007199254740991 (2^53-1).
The value that you try to pass in is simply too big for this datatype. If you really need such large numbers, try to use BigInt.
Example:

```
const largeNumber1 = 9999999999999999;
-> 10000000000000000
const largeNumber2 = BigInt(9999999999999999n)
-> 9999999999999999n
```

Make sure you use the n letter. BigInts also support all arithmetical operations.

```
9999999999999999n + 9999999999999999n;
-> 19999999999999998n
```

Comment: How would I apply BigInt in this situation?

Comment: If I understand the connection of posted question and code snippet, then, since the only number that you have is Threshold, you should change the type of Threshold in the interface definition from number to BigInt.

Comment: You can set the target version in tsconfig.json to "ES2020" or "ESNEXT". That will probably fix your issue. But be aware, because the modern versions of compiled JavaScript are not supported by all browsers.

Comment: Probably it is my fold. The datatype in the interface should be `bigint` (lowercase).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Target version is already set, datatype in the interface is also bigint now, there are no more errors when compiled. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I've set the blankActualBudget Threshold to BigInt(0n) or even 0n, and it still changes 9999999999999999 to 10000000000000000 on the field. I'm not sure why.